Fuel poured from fuel line directly into spark plug well, while plug was removed
Heres my concern, while i was working on my 2000 cadillac catera I had a visitor whom decided to turn the key in the ignition to the "ON" position for their own interest. Which I am still unsure of...
But needless to say I had one spark plug removed as well as my coil pack, and to do that of course I had to disconnect my fuel lines first.
Just as well, this so happen to be a time that I hadn't disconnected the battery cables, either.
So now I left myself wide open to having the fuel pour directly from the fuel line into my 1st spark plug well(spark plug still seeted), and my 2nd spark plug well(spark plug entirely removed).
I of course hollered and they turned the key off, cutting the gas flow off immidiately, while I simultaneously soaked up all that I could with my shop rag.
My question now is, will it still be safe for me to re-insert my spark plug and coil pack, moving forward as usual with starting my engine?
If not advised, any suggestion on which steps to take now, so I can move forward with my vehicle maintenance and driving it asap?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Thank You for the reply and assistance, hydrolock is what I was worried about. Sheesh, just when I thought my work here was done.  If you don't mind, can you please let me kno how I am supposed to turn the engine over via the starter? Would i do so by simply cranking it over with the key, or???

Depending on how much fuel was put into the cylinder (and it wouldn't take much), you need to remove as much as you can. The easiest way to do this is by leaving the sparkplug out and spinning the engine over via the starter. This will cause most, if not all, of the fuel in the cylinder to exit from the spark plug hole. Put a rag over the hole while you're doing this to catch as much fuel as you can. You'd need to do this for several revolutions of the engine. Now, you'd have the same problem as before if you kick on the ignition, which is fuel flowing in. To alleviate that, you should pull the fuel pump relay or fuse, however your vehicle is equipped (may have both). It can be found in the under hood fuse box.
The reason it is important to do this is because if you just installed the spark plug and tried to start it, if there is fuel in the cylinder, you can get your engine into a hydrolock condition. This can cause damage to the engine.
The other thing is (and this is two-fold), if there is an appreciable amount of fuel in the cylinder for any amount of time, some of the fuel is going to go past the rings and into the oil. This will dilute the oil. You'll probably want to change the oil because of this. Secondly, the fuel could also wash down the cylinders. This would mean there is no lubrication between the cylinder and the rings, which can also cause damage. To alleviate this, you could put a small squirt of oil down the spark plug hole to try and re-lubricate the cylinder. I say a "small" amount because you don't want to have too much in there as it can cause a hydrolock condition as well. One squirt directed as best as you can towards the cylinder (not towards the piston) should do the trick. This is easiest if the piston is at bottom dead center (BDC) or at the lowest position in the cylinder. Put the oil in and then turn the engine over again a few times before trying to start it.

If you can remove either fuel pump fuse or fuel pump relay, try removing the fuse for the spark system. If you can't find the fuse for spark, it may ignite fuel vapors from spark generated during starting. Or remove the ECM fuse(s). This disables the entire EFI system; no spark, no fuel pump operation, no injector operation. Crank the engine to force out any excess fuel in cylinders. Once cleared of raw fuel in cylinders, plugs back in, fuses replaced, you should be able to startup immediately.

@FDryer - Sage point ... thanks for the add.
